# spring boot - component scan beans defined in spring.xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am developing an application using spring boot.I have added some legacy dependency libraries that have xml configuration. I would like to use the beans defined in spring.xml file. I have added the package in my component scan , however the bean doesn't seem to be picked up. Should I add any additional configuration for spring boot to read xml configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import beans from xml (one application context) to annotation/java config (another application context) like below.

```
@ImportResource("classpath:spring.xml")
```

Add this into your **main** class of your spring boot application.

Now, all the beans defined in your legacy spring.xml will be available in this Spring Boot application's Application Context.

Comment: Thanks a lot @sundararaj!

Comment: Glad to help @Punter Vicky